# Reading and storing the random values of multiple JButtons on a gridLayout | Java SWING Finding a triplet

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, grid-layout, mouselistener

I'm trying to implement [Finding a triplet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-triplet-sum-two-equals-third-element/) exercise as SWING GUI, where there's a grid of random numbers and the user clicks three numbers. If the first two sums up to the third it increments a counter of correct tries. Trying to understand how can I store each clicked number in an object, so I could check for correctness.

I'm trying to understand where should I implement the actionListener, at the Square class or the Board class, and how to get and store the value of each clicked button

This is as far as I got in the matter of getting the first value, but have no idea how to read it outside the actionListener, or how to get the other values.

```java
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==finish)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You made " + wrongs + "correct tries.");
            else{
                Square sqr = (Square) e.getSource();
                int num = sqr.getNum();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to understand the principle of how to tackle such a problem. I have a feeling there's a whole different approach needs to be taken.

Comment: This depends on how you organize your code, one possibility is to implement a component with global visibility(an example Singleton Patter)

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo yes, but how can I store it into a variable outside the actionListener? e.g. int a = the_value_of_the_button_I_clicked. Or should I do all the calculations inside the actionListener? and if so, how to store all three clicks?

Comment: Depends, an example, if you want get all sequence of the click is better using an list and in the actionListener decide when execute the operation, or another example is calculate with a unique variable in the singleton, this is an example of the code, in the your actionListener -> `SingletonContainer.getInstance().sum(num)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution not is a unique, but the resposte is depends.

If you want give the sequence of the click with the numbar I think is better using an List.

If you want give only result of the sum is better using unique veriable.

An example solution, if Suppose we use a component with global visibility (although object-oriented programming does not recommend these components with global visibility)

```
public class SingletonGame{

    private static final SingletonGame SINGLETON = new SingletonGame();

    public static SingletonGame getInstance(){
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    private int sum;
    //or
    private List<Integer> operations = new ArrayList<>();

    private SingletonGame(){}

    public int getSum(){
        return sum;
    }

    //or
    public List<Integer> getOperations(){
        return operations;
    }

    public void addSum(int num){
        this.sum += num;
    }

    //or
    public void addOp(int num){
        this.operations.add(num);
    }

    publi void getResult(){
        //inside this method you have your logic
        //for calculate result
    }

}

//Inside your action

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==finish)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You made " + wrongs + "correct tries.");
            else{
                Square sqr = (Square) e.getSource();
                int num = sqr.getNum();
                // you must do control when is case for call SingletonGame.getInstance().getResult();
                SingletonGame.getInstance().sum(num);

            }
        }
    }
```